Transaction trace for Blockchain GPT
I just read a paper, Blockchain Large Language Model. The article describes the architecture of GPT models that use Ethereum data for training and can ultimately act as a real-time Intrusion Detection System.
My question is, how can I find this data? Calls and logs can be easily fetched from various providers, but what about state traces? Is there any provider where I can fetch this data for free? Also, as you see in the article, the data should specify the relationship between traces, because I ultimately want to generate a tree representation from them.
